# Vee Validate custom cross-field rule, comparing two time strings

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate

I have two time strings in my buefy form in vue that i want to validate the second one according to the first one, to only input no more than a one hour difference. I have the fields granularity to miliseconds.

my script

```
import { Validator } from 'vee-validate';

//Cross-field Rules
Validator.extend('isOneHour', (value, [otherValue]) => {
  function toSeconds(time_str) {
    // Extract hours, minutes and seconds
    var parts = time_str.split(':');
    var mili = time_str.split('.')
    // compute  and return total seconds
    return parts[0] * 3600 + // an hour has 3600 seconds
      parts[1] * 60 +   // a minute has 60 seconds
      +parts[2]        // seconds
      + mili[0] / 1000;        //miliseconds

  }
  console.log(value, otherValue); // out
  var difference = Math.abs(toSeconds(value) - toSeconds(otherValue));


  return difference <= 3600;
}, {
    hasTarget: true
  });
```

my template:

```
<b-input
            @keyup.native.enter="getData()"
            editable
            :value="startTime"
            @change.native="startTime = $event.target.value"
            placeholder="ex. 11:22:00.000"
            icon="clock"
            v-mask="'##:##:##.###'"
            name="startTime"
            ref="endTime"
          ></b-input>
<b-input
            editable
            name="endTime"
            :value="endTime"
            @change.native="endTime = $event.target.value"
            placeholder="ex. 11:25:30.450"
            icon="stopwatch"
            @keyup.native.enter="getData()"
            v-mask="'##:##:##.###'"
            v-validate="'isOneHour:endTime'"
          ></b-input>
```

this code does not work, it will create an endless loop, which will cause the app to crash. it works before the: 
`var difference = Math.abs(toSeconds(value) - toSeconds(otherValue));`

my console error is: `TypeError: time_str.split is not a function`

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So! the problem was that my **events** on the Vee Validate was set to "" and after I set it to `"blur"` the validation triggered. 
Although the error was coming from `error.first('symbol_input)` which according to my `errorBagName` should have been `vErrors.first('symbol_input')`. 
If anybody gets stuck on this like me maybe this answer will be where they went wrong.